# can we fill color in toggle-off icon of font awesome?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

[image: toggle-off font awesome icon]

`<i class="fa fa-toggle-off"  style="color:red" ></i>`

currently , I am using above class and style for toggle off icon

I want to show it as shown below

[image]

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that icon you cannot get what you want.
As an alternative, you can use **fas fa-toggle-on** and rotate it for 180deg.
**CodePen**: https://codepen.io/kitchup/pen/yYeMXE

```
//HTML
<span class="toggle-off">
  <i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i>  
</span>

//CSS
.toggle-off{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="color: red">
    <i class="fa fa-toggle-off"></i>
</span>
```

You'll need to use something like this.